# GPU out of memory on evaluation : Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

The model trains fine when I only train and don't validate, however it runs out of memory during evaluation, but I don't understand why this might be a problem especially since I am using `torch.no_grad()` any ideas?

```py
def test(epoch,net,testloader,optimizer):
    net.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    idx = 0
    features_all = []
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(testloader):
        with torch.no_grad():
            idx = batch_idx
            # inputs, targets = inputs.cpu(), targets.cpu()
            if use_cuda:
                inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
            inputs, targets = Variable(inputs), Variable(targets)
            save_features, out, ce_loss = net(inputs,targets)
            test_loss += ce_loss.item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
            total += targets.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(targets.data).cpu().sum().item()
            features_all.append((save_features, predicted, targets.data))
    test_acc = 100.*correct/total
    test_loss = test_loss/(idx+1)
    logging.info('test, test_acc = %.4f,test_loss = %.4f' % (test_acc,test_loss))
    print('test, test_acc = %.4f,test_loss = %.4f' % (test_acc,test_loss))
    return features_all, test_acc
```

Comment: `features_all.append((save_features, predicted, targets.data))`. If you're saving tensors directly, you may be saving references to them and then the CUDA memory won't be released when loop goes to next iteration. Try without this line and check.

Comment: That worked! So, I should move the tensors to cpu and then save them?

Comment: Yes, move to CPU and then save. I'll add this as an answer and you can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
features_all.append((save_features, predicted, targets.data))
```

This line is saving references to tensors in GPU memory and so the CUDA memory won't be released when loop goes to next iteration (which eventually leads to the GPU running out of memory). Move the tensors to CPU (using `.cpu()`) while saving them.